# Program doesn't record audio when using start_stream

Tags: python, pyaudio

I want to record audio with PyAudio in Python. I'm using this code:

```py
import pyaudio
import time

WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

It doesn't record and play audio, but finishes with error. If I run it from console, it prints:

```
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Full output is here: https://pastebin.com/JR5ADT3p

What I should do?

Comment: I have no experience with pyaudio but their example on the documentation page (http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) does more than you currently do. Have you tried that one yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def record(duration=3, fs=8000):
    nsamples = duration*fs
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=fs, input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=nsamples)
    buffer = stream.read(nsamples)
    array = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype='int16')
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
    return array

my_recordvoice = record() # say something
```